# Adding records to existing form page from dialogue window in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form on my page that has some standard type questions, I then have a section where the user clicks a dialogue box to search for contacts and when chosen the contact gets added to the main form window. The user can do this as many times as they want.

Has anyone figured a way in JQM to make it inject the data from the dialogue into a div or li on the parent page?

Thanks
James F.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page you are adding to known? Or the div / li you want to use? If so, you could simply hardcode a selector:

```
$("#div_up_update").append("user selection");
```

You could also just access the page and an element in there:

```
$("#page_id #div").append("user selection");
```

Let me know if you need more samples, after you provide a snippet of your code...

Hope this helps